# Print all div content with jquery printElement

Tags: jquery, printing

I am trying to print my div content using [printElement](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/) plugin. The div has a lot of text with in so there is a scrollbar. The problem is that plugin prints only the part of text which is actually on the screen. How can I print all of the text?

EDIT:

I need a solution which will print this div with styles which are in external css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1591-Ask-Ben-Print-Part-Of-A-Web-Page-With-jQuery.htm

Comment: It doesn't.  It also has browser compatability issues (IE9 confirmed).

Comment: try my plugin - https://github.com/jasonday/printThis - works with external css files

Comment: Jason, how does this work with external css files? I can't seem to find any documentation on your plugin anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jasonday/printThis

Configurable with additional css files, and other options.

Comment: I am using your plugin to print. I have a special requirement. I do see a table on the screen with no borders between the cells. But, when I print it, I want to apply the borders to the table printed on the paper. I see that there is an option to load the external css file, but How do I apply that style to the table element without affecting the one that is shown on the screen (No borders on the screen).

Comment: @Anand - you need to use a print media query to your normal stylesheet. '@media print { ... }' 
Add CSS within the brackets to affect elements on the page only for the print view.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="printclass">Print</div>
  <div id="mydivid">
        Your content goes here
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $( ".printclass" )
    .attr( "href", "javascript:void(0)")
    .click(function(){
    // Print the DIV.
    $( "#mydivid" ).print();         
    // Cancel click event.
    return( false );
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).print is not a function`.